# Beating Pass-By-Value the Best Way

Tags: c#, vector, xna, pass-by-value

(In the following code, `player` is a of a type which contains a `Vector2` called `Vector`)

```
Vector2 v = player.Vector;
v.X -= player.Speed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
player.Vector = v;
```

vs.

```
player.Vector = new Vector2(player.Vector.X - player.Speed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds, player.Vector.Y);
```

These both accomplish the same task (Getting around the "Cannot modify the return value because it is not a variable" Error), but is one more efficient than the other?

Does one use less memory? (No, right?)
Does one execute quicker?
Is there a better way?

Comment: Lol, you're just really racking off the XNA questions! :)

Comment: haha one question keeps leading to another. ur previous answer got me thinking :)

Comment: Good! Glad it did. (+1 for both the question and answer btw, I have actually always wondered this myself...I just always assumed the second was better)

Comment: I think it is really hard to say exact answer from performance point view they both quite the same (may be different in one or two or three .. but not too much,  register or argument or variable  stack copy) and it might be dependent on the compiler and low level stuff, in this kind of situation I prefer more readable code and go for the second one 
by the way in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729873/problem-with-struct-and-property-in-c-sharp the second answer shows why you get the error  "Cannot modify... " based on that Vector2 is a value type you can try to estimate the answer

Comment: everyone keeps talking about mutable structs, but keep in mind, i am not using a struct

Comment: @Evorlor you got this error because Vector2 is a struct so you are using struct look at here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.aspx

Comment: o excellent ty mojtaba. didnt know :) i always thought of it as a class (player)

Comment: @Evorlor look at the second answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729873/problem-with-struct-and-property-in-c-sharp this post it is good to know that why you get the error of "Cannot modify the return value because it is not a variable"
when you are working with struct (in case you do not know)

Comment: Yes, i read that one about 3-4 times.  Jon Skeet rules :)

Comment: when I looked at your question I tried to remember the reason for the error I could not then I searched the error   read that too :)

Answer (score 2):

The second option is better because it doesn't mutate any objects. To improve readability I'd extract a variable like this:

```
var x = player.Vector.X - player.Speed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
player.Vector = new Vector2(x, player.Vector.Y);
```

Comment: In your first code you do `v.X = ...` which means that you are mutating your vector. Using a variable `x` allows you to construct a new vector with the values you need.

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  What would be a good phrase to google? :)

Comment: @Evorlor, some people think mutating can be dangerous, like is suggested here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/14/to-box-or-not-to-box-that-is-the-question.aspx?PageIndex=4