# How do I change the y scale of my player in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try this code it gives me the following error: "Cannot modify Transform.localRotation because it's not a variable."

```
public Transform Player;
public float speed = 12f;
bool isGrounded;

if (Input.GetKey("left ctrl") && isGrounded)
{
     speed = 6f;

     Player.localScale.y = 0.5f;
}
else
{
     speed = 12f;
     Player.localScale.y = 1f;
}
```

Comment: The error says `Transform.localRotation` .. how is this related to the scaling?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Transform.localScale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localScale.html) is a [`Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html) [**property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) as well as the [`Transform.localRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localRotation.html) a [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) [**property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) which are both [**`struct`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct) and thereby [**value type**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types) properties.

You can't just change a field of them because it would only change a field in the `struct` **value** returned by the getter of the property but never call the setter of the property with the new value.

You rather have to reassign the entire value like e.g.

```
// Store in a temporary variable
var scale = Player.localScale;
// Now in a variable (or field) you CAN change the field values
scale.y = 0.5f;
// Assign back to the property
Player.localScale = scale;
```

---

See also [Problem with struct and property in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729873/problem-with-struct-and-property-in-c-sharp)